# How to engrave an arpeggio with arrow over two voices in Lilypond?

Tags: lilypond, arpeggios

I want to connect notes from two voices with an arpeggio and that the arpeggio has an arrow pointing down. I was able to create the arpeggio so that it connects the voices, however `\arpeggioArrowDown` doesn't seem to work the way as the documenation suggests. How would I get the down arrow in such an arpeggio?

This is what I want (GIMP'ed):

[image]

This is what I get:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\version "2.20.0"
\score{
  \new Staff \with { \consists "Span_arpeggio_engraver" }
  {
    \relative c'' {
      \set Staff.connectArpeggios = ##t
      << 
      { g4 \arpeggio g g g } \\
      { \arpeggioArrowDown <g, c>1 \arpeggio } 
      >>
    }
  }
  \layout{}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since connecting an undirected arpeggio symbol across voices does work,
you could just temporarily change the arpeggio symbol:

```
\set Staff.connectArpeggios = ##t
\once \override Staff.Arpeggio.arpeggio-direction = #DOWN
<< 
{ g4\arpeggio g g g } \\
{ <g, c>1\arpeggio } 
>>
```